# Cast list of interfaces to list of concrete type

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that get's some objects from a db:

```
public <T extends Persistable> List<T> getAllEntitiesEager(
        Class clazz, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
        Map<String, Object> filters, boolean invalidate);
```

This method returns a list of objects from type `clazz`. All objects returned implement the Interface `Persistable`. Now I need a List of concrete types. Is this even possible?

Example:

The Class `UserEntity` implements `Persistable` and I want to do something like that:

```
List<UserEntity> userList = (List<UserEntity) 
        someObject.getAllEntitiesEager(UserEntity.class,...)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just change the type of `clazz` to `Class<T>`?

```
public <T extends Persistable> List<T> getAllEntitiesEager(Class<T> clazz, 
                            String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, 
                            Map<String, Object> filters, boolean invalidate);
```

With this, the returned list will be of same type as you pass the `clazz` type.

Comment: Ahhh...must have been blind :D. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

You method signature should declare the generic class type `Class<T> clazz` so the returned `List` will be with from same class type:

```java
public <T extends Persistable> List<T> getAllEntitiesEager(Class<T> clazz, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters, boolean invalidate);
```

And *yes* it is feasible :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this type of code.

```
List<? extends yourParentClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with autoboxing if you change `Class clazz` to `Class<T> clazz`... I don't have a development env to test this sorry

Comment: Where does auto-boxing come from?

Comment: What autoboxing have to do with this?